# Possible value for server role

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, configuration, farm

I am trying to see what are possible values for Server Role property in SharePoint Farm

Below is the command I am using to see all servers and their roles.

```
Get-SPServer | Select Role
```

What I am getting currently is Invalid and Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of possible values for the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerRole` enumeration in the corresponding [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spserverrole(v=office.15).aspx).

These are:

> - Invalid: Specifies that the server does not have a registered role in the configuration database.
> - WebFrontEnd: Specifies that the server is a front-end Web server within the SharePoint Foundation deployment.
> - Application: Specifies that the server runs a Web application.
> - SingleServer: Specifies that the server is the only server in the SharePoint Foundation deployment.

According to the TechNet article ["Add web or application servers to farms in SharePoint 2013"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc261752.aspx) SharePoint "itself" determines the `SPServerRole` according the running services on each server (choosing between `Application` and `WebFrontEnd`).

> ### Determine server role
>
> To add a new server to the farm, you must know its intended role to plan for additional or specialized configurations and assess the potential effect of adding the server to a production environment.
>
> [...]
>
> After you determine the role of the server in your farm topology, you must identify the services and features that must be configured for the server to meet this role. **This information will determine how SharePoint 2013 is configured to provision the server for its role in either the web tier or the application tier.**

Also a server hosting Central Administration is considered to be an application server:

> ### Application server role
>
> By default, the server that hosts Central Administration in a three-tier farm is an application server. You can add application servers to host services that can be deployed to a single server and used by all the servers in a farm.

Comment: Are these values being assigned by SharePoint based on Services running on each server? How SharePoint determines difference between "Application" and "WebFrontEnd" server?

Comment: See my updated answer with some explanations from TechNet.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that select servers and check if "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" service was started on it.

```
Get-SPServer | Select Name,Role, @{Name="IsWFE";Expression={$_.ServiceInstances | Where {$_.TypeName -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"} }  }
```